# Cannot login to CP importing db

Tags: control-panel, login, security, cookies

I'm using **EE v .3.4.4** and have used a dump of the site's live database to keep my development machine in sync from time to time.  This has not been a problem in this project until last week.

After importing the live DB last week, I was unable to login to the CP.  I have the continual loop of the login page being redisplayed.

So I cleared the `exp_security_hashes` table and the `exp_sessions` table.

This did not fix the issue.
Adding 
`$config['cookie_domain'] = "";`
to master config works.

But I do not want to keep this as a fix as this is not the correct cookie domain.

What is the correct permanent solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Dorothy

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple solution is to set configurations based on environment. This is a hacky example, but totally works. For a single variable, you could do this in your config file:

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'mysite.local'){
    $config['cookie_domain'] = "";
} else {
    $config['cookie_domain'] = "mysite.com";
}
```

There are way more robust ways to do this. Look into setting environment variables via your environment.